# Pixel-art and multiple screen resolution

Tags: android

I am designing a game in pixel-art style, where everything is tiled with `16x16` tiles, old school snes style. I am designing the game to be played in landscape mode, where the height of the game is 20 tiles high.

```
20*16 = 320px.
```

If the device height is not divisible by `320 px`, am I doomed to some loss in the quality if I want to stretch it to the entire height?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you will lose some resolution in a pixel art. I guess you scale the art in the game engine if it supports it or just increase the height to make it fit the mobile screen. Some game engines do support auto scaling .